# Create 2 column flex box with minimum height

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML layout:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

The number of children and their heights can vary. Is it possible to style the parent element to divide the children into two columns, such that the parent takes the minimum possible height?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 1500px; /* I want to remove this */
}

.child {
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nunc gravida, bibendum magna ut, rutrum dui. Vivamus pulvinar, tellus at tempor imperdiet, elit lectus eleifend dui, in molestie nisi mauris at sem. Nulla varius sapien ipsum, sed semper
      nisl lacinia vel. Maecenas aliquet, ante eu feugiat iaculis, massa diam tincidunt est, id ornare nisi massa nec arcu. Nunc porta leo at diam aliquam eleifend. Cras vel diam dignissim, egestas lacus in, egestas ipsum. Aliquam ultricies justo et magna
      dignissim auctor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
    <p>Nam scelerisque hendrerit efficitur. Fusce quam mi, viverra ut enim sit amet, viverra dignissim tortor. Quisque laoreet eros sit amet ex rutrum pharetra. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi tortor orci, hendrerit vel diam et, rhoncus pellentesque quam. Donec nec porttitor urna. Nam interdum a tellus in bibendum. Etiam ac ultricies elit.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 4</h3>
    <p>Morbi quis tortor interdum, ornare nibh interdum, maximus quam. Praesent elit urna, sodales sed mollis in, euismod quis ex. Maecenas nec tellus eu lectus varius placerat sed id eros. Donec imperdiet vulputate neque at varius. Sed nunc mauris, pretium
      pretium fringilla ut, consequat sit amet ligula. Aliquam velit odio, pharetra at tincidunt ut, interdum ut augue. Mauris ultrices, mi et congue accumsan, tellus nisl semper justo, ut consectetur purus tellus ut ipsum. Suspendisse a neque eros. Suspendisse
      sit amet lacus id tortor porta lobortis. Nam tincidunt, sem id porta congue, lectus dui iaculis enim, ac tristique erat mauris et mauris. Praesent neque mi, semper ornare ullamcorper eget, commodo a mauris. Curabitur sed commodo diam, a ullamcorper
      quam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 5</h3>
    <p>Sed sit amet sem metus. Pellentesque id rhoncus felis, nec condimentum ligula. Aliquam porta erat sapien, ac efficitur nisi blandit a. Nulla congue urna ac nisi tempor ultrices. Nunc eget risus ut tortor iaculis facilisis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 6</h3>
    <p>Fusce malesuada et magna eu dapibus. Vivamus aliquam venenatis libero, quis lobortis ante luctus nec. Nullam vel lectus justo. Etiam diam turpis, auctor in finibus eget, eleifend vel ex. Curabitur sit amet neque ex. Nulla dapibus placerat tortor,
      ac viverra arcu finibus mattis. Donec vel sem urna. Phasellus pretium ultricies ipsum, eu mollis magna rutrum sed. Mauris varius accumsan diam, a aliquet nibh tincidunt ac. Proin lobortis nunc eget enim pharetra, eu lobortis nisi placerat. Aliquam
      enim tortor, viverra non posuere ut, dapibus sed elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 7</h3>
    <p>Sed molestie congue lacinia. Proin cursus laoreet magna, a pharetra odio consequat et. Donec et ullamcorper massa. Fusce eu dapibus felis. Cras condimentum purus et eros finibus aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed sit amet sem metus. Pellentesque
      id rhoncus felis, nec condimentum ligula. Aliquam porta erat sapien, ac efficitur nisi blandit a. Nulla congue urna ac nisi tempor ultrices. Nunc eget risus ut tortor iaculis facilisis.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqLYjE

In the above example, I was able to achieve the two column layout by setting `height` for the `parent` element. I want to do it without setting the `height`. Is it possible?

Setting `flex-direction` to `row` is ugly, as there will be whitespace between two vertical child elements when the height of children on a single row are unequal.

Comment: Not with `flexbox`...in order to wrap a column needs a definite height (or some other similar restriction) so it knows that it's supposed to wrap. Otherwise it would just keep on going as a single column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need the `column` propertie and not the `flex` model.

[forked pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RPYMBM)

```css
.parent {
  -moz-column-count:2;
  column-count:2;
  -moz-column-gap:0;
  column-gap:0;
  margin: 0 -5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.child {
  margin: 0 5px 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border: 1px #ccc solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 1</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed et nunc gravida, bibendum magna ut, rutrum dui. Vivamus pulvinar, tellus at tempor imperdiet, elit lectus eleifend dui, in molestie nisi mauris at sem. Nulla varius sapien ipsum, sed semper
      nisl lacinia vel. Maecenas aliquet, ante eu feugiat iaculis, massa diam tincidunt est, id ornare nisi massa nec arcu. Nunc porta leo at diam aliquam eleifend. Cras vel diam dignissim, egestas lacus in, egestas ipsum. Aliquam ultricies justo et magna
      dignissim auctor.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 2</h3>
    <p>Nam scelerisque hendrerit efficitur. Fusce quam mi, viverra ut enim sit amet, viverra dignissim tortor. Quisque laoreet eros sit amet ex rutrum pharetra. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 3</h3>
    <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi tortor orci, hendrerit vel diam et, rhoncus pellentesque quam. Donec nec porttitor urna. Nam interdum a tellus in bibendum. Etiam ac ultricies elit.

    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 4</h3>
    <p>Morbi quis tortor interdum, ornare nibh interdum, maximus quam. Praesent elit urna, sodales sed mollis in, euismod quis ex. Maecenas nec tellus eu lectus varius placerat sed id eros. Donec imperdiet vulputate neque at varius. Sed nunc mauris, pretium
      pretium fringilla ut, consequat sit amet ligula. Aliquam velit odio, pharetra at tincidunt ut, interdum ut augue. Mauris ultrices, mi et congue accumsan, tellus nisl semper justo, ut consectetur purus tellus ut ipsum. Suspendisse a neque eros. Suspendisse
      sit amet lacus id tortor porta lobortis. Nam tincidunt, sem id porta congue, lectus dui iaculis enim, ac tristique erat mauris et mauris. Praesent neque mi, semper ornare ullamcorper eget, commodo a mauris. Curabitur sed commodo diam, a ullamcorper
      quam.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 5</h3>
    <p>Sed sit amet sem metus. Pellentesque id rhoncus felis, nec condimentum ligula. Aliquam porta erat sapien, ac efficitur nisi blandit a. Nulla congue urna ac nisi tempor ultrices. Nunc eget risus ut tortor iaculis facilisis.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 6</h3>
    <p>Fusce malesuada et magna eu dapibus. Vivamus aliquam venenatis libero, quis lobortis ante luctus nec. Nullam vel lectus justo. Etiam diam turpis, auctor in finibus eget, eleifend vel ex. Curabitur sit amet neque ex. Nulla dapibus placerat tortor,
      ac viverra arcu finibus mattis. Donec vel sem urna. Phasellus pretium ultricies ipsum, eu mollis magna rutrum sed. Mauris varius accumsan diam, a aliquet nibh tincidunt ac. Proin lobortis nunc eget enim pharetra, eu lobortis nisi placerat. Aliquam
      enim tortor, viverra non posuere ut, dapibus sed elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Heading 7</h3>
    <p>Sed molestie congue lacinia. Proin cursus laoreet magna, a pharetra odio consequat et. Donec et ullamcorper massa. Fusce eu dapibus felis. Cras condimentum purus et eros finibus aliquam. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed sit amet sem metus. Pellentesque
      id rhoncus felis, nec condimentum ligula. Aliquam porta erat sapien, ac efficitur nisi blandit a. Nulla congue urna ac nisi tempor ultrices. Nunc eget risus ut tortor iaculis facilisis.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly, but for the lack of IE9 support.

Comment: `flexbox` isn't supported in IE9 either!

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks for pointing in out. Another issue is that this works only with equal width columns.

Comment: That's a great CSS attribute, thanks for the hint! In IE9 the attribute is simply ignored, causing an one-column list. That's not perfect, but still an acceptable fallback.